# Boton que cuenta y agrega datos Excel VBA

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, vba, loops, macros

Tengo que hacer un formulario que cuando yo presione un boton me agregue un producto a una tabla para un ticket de compra
Para eso utilice el siguiente codigo

```
Private Sub AMERICANO_Click()
Worksheets("Ticket_print").Activate
Dim L As Variant
Dim MyCount As Long
 L = Hoja2.Range(Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, 
"c")).End(xlUp).Row + 1
MyCount = Application.CountIf(Range("B1:B50"), "Americano")

     If MyCount = 0 Then
        Cells(L, 2).Value = "Americano"
        Cells(L, 1).Value = Cells(L, 1).Value + 1
        Cells(L, 3).Value = 25

     Else
    Cells(L, 1).Value = Cells(L, 1).Value + 1

     End If

  End Sub
```

Tengo el mismo codigo en dos botones distintos
Lo que tendria que hacer es que cuando presionara el boton agregaria el producto a la tabla y si el producto ya esta en la tabla entonces solamente deberia aumentar la cantidad sin volver a escribir el producto.
Cuando lo presiono una vez todo va bien(excepto que no me lo pone en la fila que queria) pero cuando lo presiono de nuevo me da lo siguiente

[image]

Si alguien podria decirme que hice mal o alguna forma de hacerlo se los agradeceria

Comment: No recuerdo los detalles de Range en VBA pero ee parece que estas estableciendo las celdas de inicio y fin mal ya que a la primera le pones el valor de final que debería ser el último y la segunda el valor de fila que debería ser primero, debería ser al revés.

Comment: Otras observaciones con la finalidad de ayudarte a que tus preguntas sean mejores, no las tienes que responder, sólo reflexiona al respecto. ¿Para qué tienes el mismo código en dos botones distintos? ¿Te refieres a que es similar para dos productos? ¿Qué tiene que ver eso con el problema en cuestión? La captura tiene demasiado espacio que no muestra información útil, debería ser recortada.

Comment: Lo que me refiero es que es similar,si presiono el boton me agregara el producto,y si lo presiono de nuevo el contador al lado izquierdo solo aumentara en uno pues es como si el productofuera agregado de nuevo pero en vez de eso solo inserta una fila  y agrega el numero 1 en vez de sumarlo ala cantidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con tu código es que al encontrar el texto ya presente en la columna, esribe el valor en la última fila en vez del lugar en donde encontró el texto.

Prueba el siguiente código

```
Dim L As Variant
Dim MyCount As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ticket_print")
sh.Activate

Dim text As String
text = "Americano"

L = sh.Range(Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "c")).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set FoundCell = sh.Range("B:B").Find(What:=text)
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    Cells(FoundCell.Row, 1).Value = Cells(FoundCell.Row, 1).Value + 1
Else
    Cells(L, 2).Value = "Americano"
    Cells(L, 1).Value = Cells(L, 1).Value + 1
    Cells(L, 3).Value = 25
End If
```

Comment: Muchas gracias eso resolvio el problema

Comment: De nada Angel !